# Interchanging limit and integral of difference quotient

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have shown that
$$
T_h(x)=
  \begin{cases}
   x+h & x\in[0,1-h]\\
   x+h-1& x\in(1-h,1]
  \end{cases}
$$
for some fixed $h\in(0,1)$ is measurable and measure preserving on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]},\lambda^1|_{[0,1]})$. Using this I want to show that for differentiable $f$ we have
$$
\int_0^1f'(x) dx = f(1)-f(0).
$$

Now using the measure preserving nature of $T_h$ I can show that
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\int_0^1 \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} dx  = f(1)-f(0)
$$

Now I am wanting to use the dominated convergence theorem to swap the order of the limit and integral. Now I am not sure if there exists an integrable function $w \in \mathcal{L}^1$ so that 
$$
\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right| \leq w(x)
$$
for all $h$. If there exists such a $w$ then I can use the dominated convergence theorem to swap the order of the limit and the integral and then I am done.

**EDIT**:
As per the first comment on this question, I don't think this approach will work. How can I show, by using the measure preserving nature of $T_h$  that for differentiable $f$

$$
\int_0^1f'(x) dx = f(1)-f(0).
$$

Comment: Functions like $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x > 0$, and $f(x) = 0$ for $x = 0$, make me doubt that we can apply the dominated convergence theorem here. The derivative of this function $f$ I give is probably not in $L^1([0,1])$, though I haven't checked it: the derivative has a term with a factor of $1/x$ in it.

Comment: I'm Not sure that you're right about the function you define, it has derivative 2xsin(1/x)-cos(1/x) which is bounded and therefore integrable on [0,1]

Comment: Sorry, I dropped a power of $2$: the function I meant is $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x^2)$. I was reading from here: http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/differentiable-real-function-with-unbounded-derivative-around-zero/